# sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, setuid

I have changed my Ubuntu super password by recovery mode;
after that, I can't run my sudo command in normal user .

I have attempted to crack my previous password in Recovery mode;
[I followed this link to crack my password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).

`$sudo`  ---In global mode throws me the below error:

> sudo: /usr/local/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

`$ ls -l sudo`  gives:

```
-r-sr-xr-x 1 root root 136808 May 29  2017 sudo
```

`/usr/local/bin$ ./sudo`   ---> I need this `/usr/local/bin` `./sudo` isn't working -- it throws the below error:

> sudo: ./sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

`/usr/bin$`  `./sudo`   --> working fine

```
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
```

I need to access my sudo command from the terminal from anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn’t have a `/usr/local/bin/sudo`, that’s what’s breaking things (not the password change). Move it out of the way:

```
/usr/bin/sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sudo{,2}
```

and then tell your shell about it:

```
hash -r
```

That will restore the `sudo` functionality you’re used to.

Answer (score 4):

I recently experienced this problem because I ran the following command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/*
```

Unfortunately /usr/bin/sudo is not owned by root and breaks as a result.

To fix the problem I booted into recovery mode which provides a scroll down menu with an option to drop down to a root shell.

From the root shell I ran the following commands:

```
# remount disks in read write mode
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all

# return ownership
chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo

# fix permissions
chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo

reboot
```

This solved my problems once I logged back in as a user.